# How do I complete this SSH tunnel from local development docker to staging database

Tags: mysql, docker, ssh, dockerfile

I can create a docker containing my project code.  It has unit tests that fail because there is no database connection.
I can log in to a server with a central database that contains our test data using SSH key and credentials.
I cannot get the docker and DB communicating.

I've tried several different suggestions, scratching and restarting this portion of the Dockerfile over the past two days.  I've searched Youtube for tutorials, Stackexchange for answers and the docker forums for reference.

If there's a step by step tutorial, that is tucked away I would love to see that too!

The docker-compose has the following:

```
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: .docker/Dockerfile
      args:
        APP_PATH: ${APP_PATH}
    image: laravel-docker
    env_file: .env
    ports:
      - 8080:80
      # We need to expose 443 port for SSL certification.
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/jumbledown
```

Inside the container, I can contact the host of the remote DB with the following:

`ssh -4 -R 8888:localhost:8888 [devname]@NN.NN.NN.NN -i ~/ident -p [portnumber]`

where:
- devname is my log in.
- NN.NN.NN.NN is the IP address of the host of the DB.
- ident is a file containing the SSH key that is copied in by a copy command contained in the Dockerfile.

The Docker file is built off `FROM php:7.1.8-apache` and installs a LOT of extra stuff now, including Xdebug.  It's too long to just copy and paste and I'm not sure what parts are relevant; I can expose at request.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to use Dockerfile to set up an SSH tunnel serving the DB to the docker container.  Right now, I'd settle for being able to manually set up the connection inside the container.

**Update** As per questions in the answer, the end result I need to create is for several developers to have local dockers and each have a tunnel to a central database that contains testing data, for our use while we code throughout the day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the PHP container to have a permanent SSH tunnel to your remote DB, you can change you Dockerfile's `COMMAND` statement (assuming the `ENTRYPOINT` is a shell) to use a script that creates the SSH tunnel in the background, similar to what you manually, wait for the SSH tunnel and then proceed to run whatever it is you want to run.

Your question lacks the details of what you're trying to achieve (permanent tunnel? only while testing? etc.)

An example to such script:

```sh
# run ssh in background (notice the "&" at the end)
ssh -4 -R 8888:localhost:8888 $DB_USERNAME@$DB_HOST -i ~/ident -p $DB_PORT &

# wait for the ssh tunnel if needed
# ...

# run the main command here
# ...
```

I'd suggest to consider a different path -
Create a new service in the docker-compose file that is dedicated to open a tunnel, and then connect to that service from your PHP service.

Comment: Hi there!  I actually started at that point, with this resource:https://github.com/phpmyadmin/docker/issues/99 . However, I was unable to figure out how where ${SSH_AUTH_SOCK} in the example was coming from, nor how to effectively debug and solve the issues I had.  The above question resulted as I went further and further down the rabbit hole.  The examples provided at https://hub.docker.com/r/kingsquare/tunnel weren't very illuminating and I was unable to find a good beginner-friendly resource to help me tackle this; if you have any suggestions, I would love to read through them!

Comment: After reviewing where I am with the current fix, we've agreed to prioritise the SSH tunnel as a service again.  Your suggestion is pretty much the correct answer, but if I could ask you to review the question I've made after returning to that image :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58428552/how-may-i-gett-an-ssh-tunnel-from-local-docker-to-remote-db-working-using-kings